# Library connection in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, lib

I have 4 files:

- main.cpp
- emcd.h
- EMCB.dll
- EMCB.lib

I want to use the functions that are in the dll.
There is not a lot of code, but it captures the essence.

```
#pragma comment(lib,"EMCB.lib")

#include "emcb.h"

int main()
{
    EMCBLibInitialize(); //DLL function
}
```

To compile, I use gcc and do it with the following command

> gcc main.cpp -l: EMCB.lib

after which I get an error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:EMCB.lib
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preprocessor statement:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"xxx.lib")
```

will not be recognized by the GCC compiler. You need to use `-l`

Comment: so I use this flag, but it cannot find * .lib even though it is in the same folder.